# Programming the Back Propagation Algorithm

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement the backpropagation algoirthm into my own net. I understand the idea of the backprop agl, however, I'm not strong with math. I'm just working on the first half of the backprop alg, computing the output layer (not worrying about partial derivatives in the hidden layer(s) yet).

I found the following code while I was searching, and *I'm looking for an explanation to one part of it*.

```
int i = 0;
    for (Neuron n : outputLayer) {
        ArrayList<Connection> connections = n.getAllInConnections();
        for (Connection con : connections) {

            double output = n.getOutput();
            double ai = con.leftNeuron.getOutput();
            double desiredOutput = expectedOutput[i];
            double errorDerivative = (output * (1-output) *(desiredOutput - output));
            double deltaWeight = learningRate * errorDerivative * ai;
            double newWeight = con.getWeight() + deltaWeight;
            con.setDeltaWeight(deltaWeight);
            con.setWeight(newWeight);
        }
        i++;
```

So, ai = con.leftNeuron.getOutput() is setting ai to be the output from the previous layer? If so, what exactly does this mean? The sum of the summation of weights that was passed to the particular neuron from the past layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AI is being set to the output value from the leftNeuron of the previous connection (whatever node that is connecting to the current one).

The way the back propagation algorithm works is by going through every layer in the ANN, and every node in it, then summing up all of the weights in that layer (each node has it's own weight), then adding in the threshold, and calculating if this number activates the next node (if number > x --> next node is activated).

What your code is doing is doing is getting all of the neurons from the output layer, getting all of their connections, getting the given neurons output, taking the weight from the previous layers left neuron, doing a bit of math, and setting the weight of the connection from the previous layer neuron to the current one from what I understand.

Here's a great link for understanding the basics of how ANN work, http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten the forward propagation (push the data through the net) to work perfectly well. However, I think I need to add an extra data structure to save the intermediate summation of weights that is being inputted to each neuron (because I was overwriting my input[][] each time haha... aka I've only been saving the summations that are fed into the output neurons.) At least, I think thats what you are saying. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, if you need any more resources about ANN let me know I've done a bit of work with them! Also don't forget to up vote and check off answers on your questions!

Comment: Thanks! I realy appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much on the right track, yeah. Calculating the output layer part of the backpropagation is done in two steps:

First, you calculate the error derivative, which in non-math wording is "what you want, minus what the output neuron gives you". If we call the output of the neuron "output", and what we actually wanted to get "desiredOutput", we end up with the formula you have in your code example:

```
double errorDerivative = (output * (1-output) *(desiredOutput - output));
```

Now that we have the derivative of the output neuron, we want to use that to update all weights between the output neuron and its input neurons, so we loop over them. To each weight we simply add the derivative, times the learning rate, *times the activation of the neuron sending information to the output neuron*. This is what the not-very-aptly named `ai` variable means - just whatever the neuron sends to the output neuron.

For a very good visual guide, I recommend https://www4.rgu.ac.uk/files/chapter3%20-%20bp.pdf - pages 3-4 (18-19).

Comment: Thanks! Awesome, so the intuitive problem that I am running into, is that my other code has an input[ ][ ] array, and each time data is propagated through a layer, the input array is overwritten with the new summations for each neuron. Basically, I need to save the summations from each neuron for each propagation (not just the weights for each neuron's connection [which I was obviously doing]). Correct?

Comment: Yeah, since you'll need to compute partial derivatives all the way down you'll definitely want to save the outputs and derivatives. And you typically don't actually update the weights until after you've computed all of the weights updates, so that one update doesn't affect a partial derivative further down.