# (Java) Partial Derivatives for Back Propagation of Hidden Layer

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Yesterday I posted a question about the [first piece of the Back propagation aglorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580316/programming-the-back-propagation-algorithm).

Today I'm working to understand the hidden layer.

Sorry for a lot of questions, I've read several websites and papers on the subject, but no matter how much I read, I still have a hard time applying it to actual code.

This is the code that I'm analyzing (I'm working in Java so its nice to look at a Java example)

```
// update weights for the hidden layer
    for (Neuron n : hiddenLayer) {
        ArrayList<Connection> connections = n.getAllInConnections();
        for (Connection con : connections) {
            double output = n.getOutput();
            double ai = con.leftNeuron.getOutput();
            double sumKoutputs = 0;
            int j = 0;
            for (Neuron out_neu : outputLayer) {
                double wjk = out_neu.getConnection(n.id).getWeight();
                double desiredOutput = (double) expectedOutput[j];
                double ak = out_neu.getOutput();
                j++;
                sumKoutputs = sumKoutputs
                        + (-(desiredOutput - ak) * ak * (1 - ak) * wjk);
            }

            double partialDerivative = output * (1 - output) * ai * sumKoutputs;
            double deltaWeight = -learningRate * partialDerivative;
            double newWeight = con.getWeight() + deltaWeight;
            con.setDeltaWeight(deltaWeight);
            con.setWeight(newWeight + momentum * con.getPrevDeltaWeight());
        }
    }
```

One real problem, here, is that I don't know how all of the methods work exactly.

This code is going through all neurons in the hidden layer, and going through each connection to each neuron in the hidden layer one by one. It grabs each of the connection's output? So, this is the summation of incoming connections (run through a Sig function probably) and then * by a connection weight? Then "double ai" is getting the input connection values to this particular node? Is it getting just one or the sum of the input to the neuron?

Then a third for loop pretty much sums up a "out_neu.getConnection(n.id).getWeight()" which I don't quite understand. Then, the desired output is the desiredOutput for the final layer node? Then ak is the actual output (summation and activation function) of each node or is it the summation+activation*weight?

**EDIT**

I started working on my own code, can anyone take a look at it?

public class BackProp {

```
public  int layers = 3; 
public int hiddenNeuronsNum = 5;
public int outputNeuronsNum = 1;
public static final double eta = .1;
public double[][][] weights; //holds the network -- weights[layer][neuron][forwardConnetion]


  public void Back(){
for(int neuron = 0; neuron < outputNeuronsNum; neuron++){
    for(int connection = 0; connection < hiddenNeuronsNum; connection++){

        double expOutput = expectedOutput[neuron]; //the expected output from the neuron we're on
        double actOutput = actualOutput[neuron];
        double previousLayerOutput = holdNeuronValues[layers-1][neuron];

        double delta = eta *(actOutput * (1-actOutput) *(expOutput - actOutput)* previousLayerOutput);
        weights[layers-1][neuron][connection] += delta; //OKAY M&M said YOU HAD THIS MESSED UP, 3rd index means end neuron, 2nd means start.. moving from left to right
    }
}


 //Hidden Layer..   

for(int neuron = 0; neuron < outputNeuronsNum; neuron++){
    for(int connection = 0; connection < hiddenNeuronsNum; connection++){

        double input = holdNeuronValues[layers-3][connection]; //what this neuron sends on, -2 for the next layer
        double output = holdNeuronValues[layers-2][connection];
        double sumKoutputs = 0;

        //for the output layer
        for (int outputNeurons = 0; outputNeurons < weights[layers].length; outputNeurons++) {      
            double wjk = weights[layers-2][neuron][outputNeurons]; //get the weight
            double expOutput = expectedOutput[outputNeurons];
            double out = actualOutput[outputNeurons];
            sumKoutputs += (-(expOutput - out) * wjk);
        }
        double partialDerivative = -eta * output * (1 - output) * input * sumKoutputs;

    }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard backpropagation algorithm where it is backpropagating the error through all the hidden layers.

Unless we are in the output layer, the error for a neuron in a hidden layer is dependent on the succeeding layer. Let's assume that we have a particular neuron *a* with synapses that connect it to neurons *i*, *j*, and *k* in the next layer. Let us also assume that the output of neuron *a* is *o<sub>a</sub>*. Then the error for neuron *a* is equal to the following expression (assuming we are using the logistic function as the activation function):

*δ<sub>a</sub>* = *o<sub>a</sub>*(1 - *o<sub>a</sub>*) × (*δ<sub>i</sub>w<sub>ai</sub>* + *δ<sub>j</sub>w<sub>aj</sub>* + *δ<sub>k</sub>w<sub>ak</sub>*)

Here, *o<sub>a</sub>*(1 - *o<sub>a</sub>*) is the value of the derivative of the activation function. *δ<sub>i</sub>* is the error of neuron *i* and *w<sub>ai</sub>* is the weight assigned to the synapse (connection) from *i* to *a*; the same applies to the remaining terms.

Notice how we are taking into account the error for *each* neuron in the *next* layer that *a* is connected to. Also notice that we are taking into account the weight accorded to each synapse. Without going into the math, it makes sense intuitively that the error for *a* is not only dependent on the errors on the neuron that *a* connects to, but is also dependent on the weights of the synapses (connections) between *a* and neurons in the next layer.

Once we have the errors, we need to update the weights of the synapses (connections) of every neuron in the *previous* layer **that connects to *a*** (i.e., we **backpropagate** the error). Let us assume that we have a single neuron *z* that connects to *a*. Then we have to adjust *w<sub>za</sub>* as follows:

*w<sub>za</sub>* = *w<sub>za</sub>* + (α × *δ<sub>a</sub>* × *o<sub>z</sub>*)

If there are other neurons (and there probably are) in the previous layer that connect to *a*, we will update their weights using the same formula as well. Now if you look at your code, you will see that this is exactly what is happening.

You are doing the following for each neuron in the hidden layer:

- You are getting a list of synapses (connections) that connect *this* neuron to the *previous* layer. This is the `connections = n.getAllInConnections()` part.
- For each connection, the code then does the following:

  - It gets the output of the neuron (this is the *o<sub>a</sub>* term i the formulas above).
  - It gets the output of the neuron that connects to *this* neuron (this is the *o<sub>z</sub>* term).
  - Then for each neuron in the output layer, it calculates the sum of the error of each output neuron times the weight from our neuron in the hidden layer, to a neuron in the output layer. Here, `sumKoutputs` is the same as what we are doing in the expression (*δ<sub>i</sub>w<sub>ai</sub>* + *δ<sub>j</sub>w<sub>aj</sub>* + *δ<sub>k</sub>w<sub>ak</sub>*). The value of the *δ<sub>i</sub>* comes from `-(desiredOutput - ak) * ak * (1 - ak)`, since this is how you calculate the error of the output layer; you can simply multiply the derivative of the activation function for the output-layer neuron to the difference between the actual and expected output. Finally, you can see that we multiply that whole thing by *wjk*; this is the same as the *w<sub>ai</sub>* term in our formula.
  - We now have all the values we need to plug into our formula to adjust the weights for every synapse that connects to our neuron from the preceding layer. The problem with the code is that it calculates some things a little differently:

    - In our formula we have *o<sub>a</sub>*(1 - *o<sub>a</sub>*) × (*δ<sub>i</sub>w<sub>ai</sub>* + *δ<sub>j</sub>w<sub>aj</sub>* + *δ<sub>k</sub>w<sub>ak</sub>*) for the error for neuron *a*. But in the code, it calculates `partialDerivative` by including `ai`. In our terms, this would be equivalent to *o<sub>a</sub>*(1 - *o<sub>a</sub>*) × *o<sub>z</sub>* × (*δ<sub>i</sub>w<sub>ai</sub>* + *δ<sub>j</sub>w<sub>aj</sub>* + *δ<sub>k</sub>w<sub>ak</sub>*). Mathematically it works out because later we end up multiplying this to the learning rate anyway (α × *δ<sub>a</sub>* × *o<sub>z</sub>*), and so it is exactly the same; the difference is just that the code performs the multiplication to *o<sub>z</sub>* earlier.
    - It then calculates `deltaWeight`, which is (α × *δ<sub>a</sub>* × *o<sub>z</sub>*) in our formula. In the code, α is `learningRate`.
    - We then update the weight by adding the delta to the current weight. This is the same as *w<sub>za</sub>* + (α × *δ<sub>a</sub>* × *o<sub>z</sub>*).
  - Now things are a little different. You can see that the code doesn't set the weight directly, but instead deals with `momentum`. You can see that by using `momentum`, we add a fraction of the previous delta to the new weight. This is a technique used in neural networks to ensure that the network doesn't get stuck in a local minima. The momentum term gives us a little "push" to get out of a local minima (a "well" in the error-surface; with a neural network we are traversing the error surface to find one with the lowest error, but we could get stuck in a "well" that isn't as "deep" as the optimal solution), and ensures that we can "converge" on a solution. But you have to be careful because if you set this too high, you can overshoot your optimal solution. Once it calculates the new weight using the momentum, it sets it for the connection (synapse).

I hope this explanation made it clearer for you. The math is a little hard to get into, but once you figure it out, it makes sense. I think the main problem here is that the code is written in a slightly different manner. You can take a look at some code [here](https://github.com/vivin/DigitRecognizingNeuralNetwork/blob/master/src/main/java/net/vivin/neural/Backpropagator.java) that I wrote that implements the backpropagation algorithm; I did this as a class project. It runs pretty much along the same lines as the formulas I described above and so you should be able to follow through it easily. You can also take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLdbWDgwiKU) I made where I explain the backpropagation algorithm.

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic, thank you so much, I'm re-reading this as we speak, and I'm working on my own code! Hopefully I'll get my own code to work haha

Comment: I can't get over how great of an answer this is, thanks again!

Comment: @NateCook3 Glad I was able to help. :)

Comment: I started writing my own code, can you take a quick look at it? I'm using arrays instead of objects. @vivin-paliath

Comment: I know the code isn't perfect/fully correct, but I've been trying to do it without referencing anyone else's code.

Comment: @NateCook3 I might be able to, but the best way to see if it works is to simply run it and see if it works. The easiest way to test it is to see if your algorithm can train a neural network to emulate the `XOR` boolean operator.